# Batch download web links on Android?

Tags: downloading

I have plenty of web links to some images and I want to download all of them on my Android device in queue.

I have searched words *download manager* on Play Store but those applications seem to support adding single link only; rather than importing multiple links from a file or clipboard.

I also tried to install Firefox and its extension DownThemAll! But no matter what version of Firefox for Android I installed, the application always show "extension is not compatible"

Can anybody tell me is there any way for me to batch download web links on my Android device?

Comment: For the Firefox "extension is not compatible" problem, see [Firefox version 21 installed easily but greasemonkey won't install](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46957/12442)

Answer (score 1):

Wget should work, and can be installed to Android if it's not already there.
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Just use it in a terminal emulator.

Comment: Good idea, NoBugs! Maybe you should include how "Batch mode" is supposed to work with it -- especially for people not used to the shell :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of this or an usage instruction please?