# Firefox version 21 installed easily but greasemonkey won't install - error saying not compatible with ver 21

Tags: firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

I can't find anyone with this problem of not being able to install greasemonkey since installing Firefox version 21 on my android. My ultimate goal is to combine my fitness pal logging with weight watchers so that mfp will calculate ww points. It can be done but only through using greasemonkey. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you also tried the latest developer snapshot from https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ (scroll down to devel channel to see 1.10b1)? Besides this: your problem seems rather app specific, I suggest you better ask over at mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in this case is misleading: it's not that Greasemonkey is incompatible with that version *number*, rather that it's incompatible with Firefox for Android. The extension mechanism in Firefox for Android is somewhat different to Firefox on desktops, so add-ons for desktop Firefox won't work (in general) on Android.

To find out if/when Android support is planned, or to help out, you could start by contacting the [gresemonkey-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/greasemonkey-users).

Comment: Thanks! Apparently my issue can't resolved after doing more research. I appreciate your input though :).